# Does Pydroid recognize random.choice?

Tags: python, pydroid

Here is my code

```
user_action = input("enter rock, paper, or scissors:  ")
possible_action = ["rock", "paper", "scissors"]
computer_action = random.choice(possible_action)
```

and it tells me that it's an invalid variable.

Am I doing something wrong or is it Pydroid's fault?

Comment: What do you mean by "it's an invalid variable"?

Comment: It says "undefined variable 'random' " E0602

Answer (score 1):

The only possible issue is that you forgot to

> import random

This code is working perfectly fine:

```
import random
user_action = input("enter rock, paper, or scissors:  ")
possible_action = ["rock", "paper", "scissors"]
computer_action = random.choice(possible_action)
print(computer_action)
```

Comment: Are you using Pydroid?

Comment: No, I am not using pydroid

Comment: Okay, thanks alot! Importing fixed the issue. I had no idea I had to import